# incorrect type inferring

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have following code:

```
SomeInterface self = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(sessionContext.getInvokedBusinessInterface());
```

And following method signature (*from eclipse tooltip (not real code)*):

```
<Object> Object javax.ejb.SessionContext.getBusinessObject(Class<Object> arg0) throws IllegalStateException
```

For some reason return type is resolved as Object. And that is weird as eclipse does not mark this line as erroneous, however ant and maven builders fails on this line saying that Object can not be converted to SomeInterface.

I have several questions:

- what is wrong with my code, so that type inferring is incorrect (actually it should not be Object as variable type is `SomeInterface`)?
- why line is not marked as erroneous in eclipse (bug)?

I have following example which is correctly compiled under eclipse, but fails in maven:

```
public class TestClass implements SomeInterface {
    private Resolver resolver;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TestClass() {
        SomeInterface c = resolver.some(resolver.someClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void something() {
    }
}

class Resolver {
    public <T> T some(final Class<T> c) {
        return null;
    }

    public Class someClass() {
        return null;
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
    void something();
}
```

Here type is inferred correctly (*from eclipse tooltip (not real code)*):

```
 <SomeInterface> SomeInterface Resolver.some(Class<SomeInterface> c)
```

But this class still can not be compiled with maven compiler.

I am using eclipse juno.

**UPD**

Maven failure:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project jpharm-server: Compilation failure
[ERROR] TestClass.java:[21,39] incompatible types
[ERROR] found   : java.lang.Object
[ERROR] required: SomeInterface
```

Comment: what is the error you get from maven building your TestClass?

Comment: @guido, updated question with maven failure

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
SomeInterface c = resolver.<SomeInterface> some(resolver.someClass());
```

to help the compiler.

The specific example you give should not compile. The compiler, when applying type inference, tries to find the most specific type that suits all the operands of the statement. Here, `resolver.someClass()` returns a `Class` which could be any class, i.e. it really is a `Class<? extends Object>` and there is no way to infer that `? extends Object` is a `SomeInterface`.

For example, `someClass` could well be:

```
public Class someClass() {
    return Object.class;
}
```

Comment: i think that was the "derived" signature eclipse was showing while hovering the method *call* with mouse pointer; not the actual source code

Comment: @guido Thank you - that makes more sense!

Comment: `The specific example you give should not compile.` But it compiles in eclipse. What is that, eclipse compiler improvement over javac? Or bug?

Comment: @michaelnesterenko In Netbeans, with jdk 7u11, I get the same compile error as Maven: `error: incompatible types: SomeInterface c = resolver.some(resolver.someClass()); required: SomeInterface found:    Object` So I suspect it is eclipse acting weird.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
public Class someClass() {
```

This returns a raw type `Class` object, which is *practically* equivalent with a `Class<? extends Object>`. You should make this method generic as well:

```
public Class<? extends T> someClass() {
```

and call it with:

```
resolver.<SomeInterface>someClass();
```

Ideally, you'd fill an actual type in the signature of your `getInvokedBusinessInterface()` so that it returns a `Class<? extends SomeInterface>`.

Comment: It's not really correct to say that `Class` is not equivalent to `Class<Object>`.

Comment: `Class` is equivalent to `Class<? extends Object>`, not to `Class<Object>`. For example, `someClass` could return `String.class` which clearly isn't a `Class<Object>`.

Comment: But in the second example inferred type is the same as variable's type

Comment: @assylias Good point, `Class<String>` is indeed a valid actualization for `Class` and `Class<? extends Object>` but not for `Class<Object>`. Updated my answer.